# Some identities from graph theory and probability

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, probability-distributions

The other day I attended a seminar about probability. I took some notes and I am now revising it and trying to understand some steps that were omitted by the lecturer. To formulate my question, consider the set $\Sigma_{N} := \{-1,+1\}^{N}$, for some $N > 1$. An element $s \in \Sigma_{N}$ will be written as $s = (s_{i})_{i=1}^{N}$. Let $\beta > 0$ be a positive parameter. Moreover, suppose for each $i,j=1,...,N$, $X_{ij}$ are i.i.d Gaussian random variables $\mathcal{N}(0,\frac{1}{N})$. For simplicity, I will write $t_{ij} := \tanh(\beta X_{ij}$. Consider the expansion:
$$\sum_{s \in \Sigma_{N}} \frac{1}{2^{N}}\prod_{i<j}(1+s_{i}s_{j}t_{ij}).$$
This sum can be expanded in terms of graphs:
$$\sum_{s \in \Sigma_{N}}\frac{1}{2^{N}}\prod_{i<j}(1+s_{i}s_{j}t_{ij}) = \sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma_{\text{sc}}}w(\gamma)$$
where $\Gamma_{\text{sc}}$ denotes the set of all simple and closed graphs, with vertices indexed by $\{1,...,N\}$ and of even degree. The factor $w(\gamma)$ means $w(\gamma) = \prod_{e \in \mathcal{E}}t_{e}$, where $\mathcal{E}$ is the set of edges of $\gamma$.

In the seminar, the lecturer mentioned a couple formulas.

- $\mathbb{E}[w(\gamma)w(\gamma')] = 0$ if $\gamma \neq \gamma'$ are distinct graphs;
- $\mathbb{E}[w^{2}(\gamma)] \le \frac{\beta^{2l}}{N^{l}}$ if the set of edges $\mathcal{E}_{\gamma}$ has cardinality $l$.
- $\sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma_{\text{sc}}}\mathbb{E}[w^{2}(\gamma)] \le \prod_{\gamma \in \Gamma_{\text{loop}}}(1+\mathbb{E}[w^{2}(\gamma)])$

I don't exactly know how to prove these three bullet points. As I took it from a seminar, it is not even clear if these are like trivial results or if their proof require some more advanced machinery. Any help is welcomed!

Comment: While I think this particular question is fine for MO, I am always perplexed by these types of questions: why don't you just ask the lecturer directly (in person/via e-mail)? This way you are likely to get an answer way faster and establish a potential connection (if you don't know the lecturer yet).

Answer (score 2):

These inequalities are not too bad. Note that the $t_{ij}$ are independent and mean zero by the fact hyperbolic tangent is an odd function and symmetry of the Gaussians. This implies the first equality since given two distinct graphs, there is an edge with multiplicity one in the union as multisets. By independence, one can factor out the expectation of that edge to get zero. The second inequality follows from the simple bound $\tanh^2(x)\leq x^2$ and then taking expectations using the fact the Gaussians are normalized to variance $1/N$. The final inequality is obtained by noticing every simple and closed graph can be decomposed uniquely as the disjoint union of cycles (loops). Because terms corresponding the distinct edges are independent as above, every summand on the left side can be realized via the term on the right side obtained by choosing the expectation terms in that cycle decomposition and 1 for all other cycles.